# Avoid Signals to carry Forward next day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to write a strategy where I will take entry if two candle sustain above or below the open price of first 5 min candle. I don't want to carry forward the signal to next day(i.e) my next day should start fresh without considering the previous data points.

Could anyone please help me how to reset the data for every trading session and should consider data from only current trading session. I have attached my code for your reference.[image]

````
indicator("IBH-IBL", overlay=true)

// First 5 min vlaues

var float dayOpen = 0.0
var float dayHigh = 0.0
var float dayLow = 0.0
var float dayClose = 0.0

timeDelta = time - time[1]

dayOpen := (hour== 9 and minute == 15) ? open : dayOpen
dayHigh := (hour== 9 and minute == 15) ? high : dayHigh
dayLow := (hour== 9 and minute == 15) ? low : dayLow
dayClose := (hour== 9 and minute == 15) ? close : dayClose

plot(dayOpen,color=color.yellow, linewidth=3, title='5min yellow line')
plot(dayHigh,color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title='5min IBH')
plot(dayLow,color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title='5min IBL')

longCondition = close > dayOpen
shortCondition = close < dayOpen

twoAbovedayOpen = longCondition[1] and longCondition[2]
twobelowdayOpen = shortCondition[1] and shortCondition[2]


Trend = 0
Trend := twoAbovedayOpen ? 1: twobelowdayOpen? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
plotarrow ( Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=color.lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=color.red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should reset you `trend` flag when it is a new day.

```
is_new_day = ta.change(time("D"))
bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)

Trend = 0
Trend := is_new_day ? 0 : twoAbovedayOpen ? 1: twobelowdayOpen? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @vitruvirus!!! This code works fine as expected

Comment: No problem. Then please consider accepting my answer so we would know this question has a valid answer.

Comment: @vitruvirus I am unable to upvote...Looks like I need 15 reputation to upvote this answer.

Comment: @vitruvirus I am getting the notification"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: Hi @vitruvirus I have another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73377078/plot-historical-signal-to-current-day-session . If possible could you please look into it